# JavaFX line between two circles and centering text within circile

Tags: javafx, geometry, line, center

I am trying to write a program for a binary search tree that will put circles on a pane in JavaFX and then connect the circles with a line to make it look like a
binary search tree. I can get the circles to appear on the pane, but the line that is being created stays at the top and doesn't go from the center of the parent circle to the center of the new circle. I also want the text to be centered within the circle and I cannot get that to work either. I have posted my code below along with my output and the desired output I want.

```
public boolean addNode(T addMe) {
    boolean added = false;
    MyNode current = root;
    MyNode node = new MyNode(addMe, null, null);
    if (root == null) {
        root = node;
        added = true;
    } else {
        while (added != true) {
            if (addMe.compareTo(current.info) < 0) {
                if (current.left == null) {
                    current.left =  new MyNode(addMe, null, null);
                    added = true;
                } else {
                    current = current.left;
                }
            } else {
                if (current.right == null) {
                    current.right =  new MyNode(addMe, null, null);
                    added = true;
                } else {
                    current = current.right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    node.label = new Text("" + addMe);
    node.label.setFont(new Font(16));
    node.circle = encircle(node.label, node);
    node.label.xProperty().bind(node.circle.centerXProperty());
    node.label.yProperty().bind(node.circle.centerYProperty());
    node.edge = new Line();
    if(node != root) {   
        node.edge.startXProperty().bind(current.circle.centerXProperty());
        node.edge.endXProperty().bind(node.circle.centerXProperty());
    }
    this.getChildren().add(node.edge);
    node.edge.toBack();

    node.circle.setOnMouseDragged(evt -> {
        double mouseX = evt.getX(),
        mouseY = evt.getY();
        node.circle.setCenterX(mouseX);
        node.circle.setCenterY(mouseY);
    });
    this.getChildren().addAll(node.circle, node.label);
    return added;
}

private Circle encircle(Text text, MyNode node) {
    node.circle = new Circle();
    node.circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    final double PADDING = 10;
    node.circle.setRadius(getWidth(text) / 2 + PADDING);
    if (node == root) {
        node.circle.setStroke(Color.RED);
    } else {
        node.circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    }
    return node.circle;
}

private int getWidth(Text text) {
    new Scene(new Group(text));
    text.applyCss();
    return (int) text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
}
```

My Output: [My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEZkF.png)
Desired Output: [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lJ4e.png)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the line positioning.. you binded the x values and forgot to bind y values.

```
node.edge.startYProperty().bind(current.circle.centerYProperty());
node.edge.endYProperty().bind(node.circle.centerYProperty());
```

And regarding positioning the text, you need to move your text to half of its bounds to position it to the center of a given position. The below code may work.

```
node.label.xProperty().bind(node.circle.centerXProperty().subtract(node.circle.radiusProperty().subtract(10))); // Your PADDING value
node.label.yProperty().bind(node.circle.centerYProperty().subtract(node.circle.radiusProperty().subtract(10))); // Your PADDING value
```

If you provide a minimal example, I can give you a more accurate solution.

There can be many ways for each implementation. The below is one of the approach I may use, for the following reasons:

- group similar stuff in one class
- avoid an extra Circle node
- Don't bother about the positioning of text.

These are just my views, not sure if this can help you.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BinarySearchLayoutDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        InfoNode node1 = buildAndAddNode(root, null, "345785", 100, 100);
        InfoNode node2 = buildAndAddNode(root, node1, "2356", 200, 200);
        InfoNode node3 = buildAndAddNode(root, node1, "589", 50, 200);
        InfoNode node4 = buildAndAddNode(root, node2, "478", 280, 300);
        InfoNode node5 = buildAndAddNode(root, node2, "25", 150, 300);
    }

    private InfoNode buildAndAddNode(Pane root, InfoNode parentNode, String text, double x, double y) {
        InfoNode node = new InfoNode(text);
        node.setPosition(x, y);
        root.getChildren().add(node);
        if (parentNode != null) {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.startXProperty().bind(parentNode.centerXProperty());
            line.startYProperty().bind(parentNode.centerYProperty());
            line.endXProperty().bind(node.centerXProperty());
            line.endYProperty().bind(node.centerYProperty());
            root.getChildren().add(line);
            line.toBack();
        }
        return node;
    }

    class InfoNode extends StackPane {
        private double PADDING = 8;
        private double x;
        private double y;

        public InfoNode(String txt) {
            Text text = new Text(txt);
            double size = getWidth(text) + (2 * PADDING);
            setStyle("-fx-shape:\"M 0 0 m -5, 0 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0\";-fx-border-color:black;-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-background-color:yellow;");
            setMinSize(size, size);
            getChildren().add(text);

            widthProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> setLayoutX(x - val.doubleValue() / 2));
            heightProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> setLayoutY(y - val.doubleValue() / 2));
        }

        public DoubleBinding centerXProperty() {
            return layoutXProperty().add(widthProperty().divide(2));
        }

        public DoubleBinding centerYProperty() {
            return layoutYProperty().add(heightProperty().divide(2));
        }

        public void setPosition(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            setLayoutX(x - getWidth() / 2);
            setLayoutY(y - getHeight() / 2);
        }

        private double getWidth(Text text) {
            new Scene(new Group(text));
            text.applyCss();
            return text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        }
    }
}
```